# Running broadcast receiver on a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a class which runs on process's main thread. I want to implement a broadcast receiver in this class which runs on a separate thread.

I tried this by making a inner class extending thread & intializing a handler in this inner class, which i can give to registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler) for executing broadcast receiver on this handler(which is attached to newly created thread). but in vain. Logs show onReceive is being called on main thread.

please help.(i have seen some posts on how to use registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler), but not of any help).

Comment: OnReceive will always calls in main thread. This behavior described by android system. You can start new thread inside your receiver and do all job inside this thread.

Comment: Why you want your Broadcast Receiver to run on a separate thread ? I mean whats the objective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you should use `HandlerThread` instead of subclassing a `Thread`

for example

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("DifferentThread" , android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
handlerThread.start();
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
private Handler handler = new Handler(looper, this);
// Register the broadcast receiver to run on the separate Thread
registerReceiver (myReceiver, intentFilter, broadcastPermission, handler);
```

Hope this will help in your Experiment ;)

Njoy!

Comment: Thanks Shubhang for help. As for your above question, i needed Broadcast receiver on separate thread because it has to do some notification on receive of some intents while the class in which its being implemented is kind of utility/helper class. so running BR on separate  thread insures caller to class dnt get blocked. hope m doing right designing.

Comment: @Learner It's been a while since this was posted, but did this approach worked for you? I'm looking into the same BR architecture and would like get some feedback on your experience.

Answer (score 3):

When using a HandlerThread, be sure to exit the thread after unregistering the BroadcastReceiver. If not, File Descriptor (FD) leaks occur in Linux level and finally the application gets crashed if continue to Register / Unregister.

unregisterReceiver(...);

Then 
looper.quit(); 

Or 

looper.quitSafely();

```
private Handler broadcastReceiverHandler = null;
private HandlerThread broadcastReceiverThread = null;
private Looper broadcastReceiverThreadLooper = null;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverReadScans = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}

private void registerForIntents() {
    broadcastReceiverThread = new HandlerThread("THREAD_NAME");//Create a thread for BroadcastReceiver
    broadcastReceiverThread.start();

    broadcastReceiverThreadLooper = broadcastReceiverThread.getLooper();
    broadcastReceiverHandler = new Handler(broadcastReceiverThreadLooper);

    IntentFilter filterScanReads = new IntentFilter();
    filterScanReads.addAction("ACTION_SCAN_READ");
    filterScanReads.addCategory("CATEGORY_SCAN");

    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverReadScans, filterScanReads, null, broadcastReceiverHandler);
}

private void unregisterIntents() {
    context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverReadScans);
    broadcastReceiverThreadLooper.quit();//Don't forget
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have forked LocalBroadcastReceiver to be able to receive broadcasts on an arbitrary java thread.

it works for me. I added a Looper param to

`public void registerReceiver(Context act, IntentFilter filt, Looper looper)`

if looper is null, the main thread looper is used.

the code is here:

https://github.com/sorenoid/LocalBroadcastManager/blob/master/LocalBroadcastManager.java